# Django Broken INTERNAL link on otherIPAddress

Tags: django, apache, django-errors

Why do I get "`Broken INTERNAL link on xyz`", where xyz is NOT the IP address of the server where the website is hosted?

To be more specific: my website address is '`myExample.com`' and there is another IP address let's call it '`anotherExample`'. I get 'Broken INTERNAL link on anotherExample'. The referrer is `'http://anotherExample/somePHPFile.php'` and the Requested URL is of course `'/somePHPFile.php'`.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a 3rd party library that makes a call to another website, perhaps something like a FB or Twitter plugin? I'm just guessing here.

Comment: I also thought so in the first place but I receive some other Broken Internal Link messages from multiple IP addresses (3-5 requests every 20 minutes). The requested address is: mywebsite.com/blog/wp-login.php. I suppose this is some kind of a brute force which tries to guess the password of the wordpress blog... So I'm pretty sure some crawlers/bots are trying to do something nasty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have the middleware `django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` enabled. According to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware) it sends broken link notification emails to `MANAGERS`.

Solution: just remove the `BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` item from `MIDDLEWARES` in your `settings.py`.